# How to connect to postgres read replica in Hasura

Tags: hasura

I have the main postgres database running with Hasura. I want to add a new Hasura service that connects only to the read replica.

But it is getting this error

> ..."hint":"You can use REPEATABLE READ instead.","message":"cannot use serializable mode in a hot standby","status_code":"0A000"...

I also tried adding `--tx-iso=repeatable-read` but no luck.

Comment: Additional details -- relevant postgres configuration, Hasura service configuration, etc --would help make the question clearer.